# How to use .htaccess to reformat a directory listing while including the directory name?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

For directory listings, I've created a common .htaccess file as well as a common header ("HeaderName /header.html).

Everything works fine, except one thing: while I *don't* want the derpy h1 version of "Index of /blah", I'd like to display a customized (and normal-sized) version of that, e.g., "CurDir = /blah". By default, specifying the HeaderName replaces all of that with some static text.

I tried embedding a bit of PHP (getcwd()) but that just returned the root directory where the header.html lives, no matter what subtree was being displayed. Surely there's some way to access the CWD without having to sprinkle control files like this in each subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon what may be a suitable environment variable while looking at the phpinfo() output... but is there a better (more common) way people handle this, perhaps without even using PHP?

```
<?php
$dir = getenv("REQUEST_URI");
?>
```